# Callouts Limits Anyone?

Tags: apex, visualforce, limits, callout, httprequest

I have a Visualforce form that saves a custom object and send some fields to a REST web service in a controller method. I am using the good old httprequest to accomplish that and it works fine. This is not a @future method, so I am not supposed to be affected by the 200 call methods per license.

I know the governor limits for callouts are 10 per transaction. I am not worry about it since I only make one per transaction.

I could not find anywhere in the documentation if there are any limits of callouts we can do every 24 hs. Is there any limits on how many callouts we can do?

I want to believe that there are no limits, but sometimes Salesforce prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions (Batch Apex, **future methods**, and scheduled Apex) per a 24-hour period is 250,000 or the number of user licenses in your organization multiplied by 200, whichever is greater

for more reference check this [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_gov_limits.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I thought there was a limit but I can't find anything about it so it looks as thought it may have been lifted (if it ever did exist, now I'm second guessing myself!).

[The only real reference in the docs is the 10 per transaction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm), as you mention, and it says that the waiting time does not contribute to your CPU usage limit in a given transaction.